# how to do image caching in android

Tags: android

I have a set of images to be downloaded from their corresponding url. Can anyone tell how to proceed with caching of these images? Please reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can get an internal storage cache directory by calling `getCacheDir()` which is an exclusive area for your app to use as storage, that cant be accessed by anyone or any other app. You can also get an external storage (sd card) cache directory by calling `getExternalCacheDir()`, which in this case can be accessed by users. You can read up more about this at Androids [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) chapter on its dev guide.

In terms of downlaoding and saving the images you can do the following:

```
URL url = new URL(url); 
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
Bitmap image = Bitmap.decodeStream(ucon.getInputStream);

File cacheDir = getCacheDir();

File imageFile = new File(cahceDir, "downloadedImage.png");

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
fos.close();
fos.flush();
```

Be careful about downloading large images, as this may cause a OOM error (OutOfMemory), so you *may* wrap your bitmap object with a SoftReference object to avoid this error. i.e.

```
SoftReference<Bitmap> softref = new SoftReference(image);
```