# Does HttpClient in android do mem/disk cache when received content?

Tags: android, http, httpclient

I do not know if the HttpClient in android have a built in cache system, then I can avoid to build my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is support for caching (and a bunch of other features) in Gingerbread, but you have to switch to HttpUrlConnection.  See
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

This SO question also seems relevant:
[How to check caching in DefaultHttpClient on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675625/how-to-check-caching-in-defaulthttpclient-on-android)